# Two init methods on UIImageView/TableFooterView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

Gents, I'm trying to have an image that is set as the footer for a tableview. The footer image needs to change based on tapping a button in the nav bar. ( The design is such that there are two buttons on the nav bar, and when the screen/view is loaded, there's a certain image in the footer, tapping on one of the buttons changes it and then tapping on the other changes it back and so on).

I tried using a UIImage a a @property and then tried to change the image and set the frame on it but that didn't work (the frame wasn't set correctly). Essentially, I want to do something like this:

```
[[self table1] setfooterview : [[uiimageview alloc] initwithframe:(CGRectMake (0,0,50,50)] and then I also need to add initwithimage:[UIImage imagenamed :@"hello-1.png"]]
```

but the issue is I can't do two init methods in the same statement. And I can't create an object like UIImageView *hello or whatever since I need to use this in a different method later on (In the method where I handle the presses of the different buttons). (Later on, I'm using a simple if statement and then triggering the image on the footerview based on which button was pressed). My guess was that I might have to do something like
    [[self table1] setfooterview: [[uiimageview alloc] initwithframe :(CGRectMake (0,0,50,50)] and then do a set image but I think since setimage is not valid, I might need to cast it in some way. How would I do this?

Sorry for the terrible syntax and please ignore all the syntax errors, since my mac is not with me at the moment and I'm just typing this from memory and I'm new to iOS programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to send two init methods.  Both the image and the frame are properties of `UIImageView`.  (The `frame` property is inherited from `UIView`.)  You can just set them after sending the init message.

You could do this:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(...)];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hello-1"];
self.table1.footerView = imageView;
```

Or you could do this:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"hello-1"];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(...);
self.table1.footerView = imageView;
```

Or you could even do this:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(...);
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hello-1"];
self.table1.footerView = imageView;
```

Comment: But see the whole point is, I need to be able to use this footerview in my viewdidload and in another method later on (the click handler for both my buttons) so creating a *imageview would make it only available to that class and I won't be able to deal with in my other click handling method...

Comment: You can access it again as `self.table1.footerView`, or you can store a reference to it in an instance variable.

Comment: If you want to access it using `self.table1.footerView`, cast it back to `UIImageView` like this: `[(UIImageView *)self.table1.footerView setImage:newImage]`.

Comment: Where/How would I case this? Can you give me an example in the following way: 
Say, this is my viewdidLoad method:
HMmm, SO you're saying this would work:

- (void)viewDidLoad {
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(...);
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hello-1"];
self.table1.footerView = imageView;
}
And then I have my - (IBAction)rButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
}
How do I case it in such a way that I can handle the image on the footerview even in the rButtonPressed method and swap it out as needed? As In, how do I cast it and where?

Comment: It would be better for you to try some things yourself.  If you can't get it working, edit your question to include what you tried.

Comment: What I was struggling with is the fact that after I define stuff in viewdidload, I was unable to do something like [[self table1]footerview setimage.... since setimage is not valid on footerview. How would this work?

Comment: Look at my second comment.  It contains the statement you probably want to use.  Just replace `newImage` with whatever you need to use as the image.

Comment: Correct, but do I use this in the first method or do I do it in the second one when I want to use it for a second time?

Comment: Why don't you define a property for the image view? Well, making an UIElement accessible from external may not be the best way of doing it. You should rather keep the UIImageView internal and provide metods that receive updated values and then update the image view accordingly. But I did not get the point. What exactly stops you from doing that? Is it maybe just, that you do not know how to imlement a public method or setter of a property?

Comment: I tried the image view as a property but it didn't work ( my image wasn't being shown

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to call two init methods. 
You could subclass or extend UIImageView and implement a new init method that allows setting the frame and image in one go. But you could do the following too.

```
UIImageView footerView =  [[uiimageview alloc] initwithframe:(CGRectMake (0,0,50,50)];
footerView.image =  [UIImage imagenamed :@"hello-1.png"];
[[self table1] setfooterview: footerView];
```

Alternative which I just keyed in. This is not QAed and may not be the perfect solution but should give you a hint in the right direction. 
In your .h file add either of the two lines:

```
- (void) changeFooterImage:(UIImage *) image;
- (void) changeFooterImageNamed:(NSString *)imageName;
```

In your .m file add the correspoinding implementation:

```
- (void) changeFooterImage:(UIImage *) image {
    if (!self->footerView) {
        self->footerView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake (0,0,50,50)];
        [[self tableView] setTableFooterView: footerView];
    }
    self->footerView.image =  image;
}

- (void) changeFooterImageNamed:(NSString *)imageName{
    if (!self->footerView) {
        self->footerView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake (0,0,50,50)];
        [[self tableView] setTableFooterView: footerView];
    }
    self->footerView.image =  [UIImage imageNamed :imageName];
}
```

Your 3rd party view controller then should include the .h file of this view controller. 
A bit more "neat" and "out of the book" would be not to bind the classes directly in this way. You should prefer declaring this method(s) in a protocol and then implment the protocol and before acutally calling the method you may check whether the class implements the protocol. But I feel that all that is a bit too much new stuff at once. Go for a start with this one and implement the protocol later, when this works in principle.

Comment: Again, the issue with this is I won't be able to use this outside the method I've defined it in. I need this once in viewdidLoad and then later on in my clickhandling method.

Comment: Please explain that a little bit further. What is your problem? Do you need this solution in one single line? (In that case you could implement your own init method) Or can't you use an iVar or property to keep a reference? (My solution goes without iVar and property because you have not used one yourself). Sorry if all of this questions are wrong. I really did not (yet) understand your problem.

Comment: I tried using a property and it didn't work. Can u tell me how I would use an Ivar? Yes,keeping a reference is important because I want to set my footerview in hviewdidload and then perform some action on this same footer view in an ibaction method. C

Answer (score 0):

"I can't create an object like UIImageView *hello or whatever since I need to use this in a different method later on" what does that mean?

Any way you can initialize UIImageView and set its frame and initial image before assigning it to the footerView.

Comment: But after I assign it to the footerView, I can't access it in a different method right?